# Django single slug table and nested urls without prefix

Tags: python, django, url, slug, django-contenttypes

Ok so here is my (seemingly unique) problem:

I am trying to get a single slug table working for Django. After countless hours of researching I found out this was not a common problem as I tought. Note: I am  relativly new to Django.

**The real problem I'm trying to solve**

I want a nested slug based url without prefixes, like so:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product-name
```

but also:

```
www.example.com/category-name/brand-name
```

and so on...

There should be the possibility for a slug history so old slugs kan be redirected.

**What I have come up with so far:**

- Making a single slug table for all slugs to ensure they are globally unique
- Using django-conttenttypes as relation to Models to figure out what views to load
- Make relations within te slug table to define what should be nested and what not

  - Figure out some way to do a slug table lookup in urls.py to check if url is valid and select the correct view.

I found a Rails gem that does mostly what I want: [Friendly_Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Obviously I am making some basic design mistakes. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The Rails friendly_id gem doesn't really do any of this other than allowing you to use slugs instead of IDs, which Django pretty much supports out of the box. It certainly doesn't do anything to work across multiple models with unique slugs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input :) I was under the impression that the history module of friendly_id does somewhat te same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this question turned out to be more difficult and unique than I tought. For future reference, this is how I eventually solved the problem:

- Make 1 slug table where all slugs are unique.
- Use Django ContenType to make [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) between the slug in the slug table and the entity it belongs to.
- Made a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/) request rewriter that rewrites the segments of an slug based url to an non slug url, like so: `test.com/category-slug/product-slug` to `test.com/category/6/product/12`, using the generic relation.
- Use the rewritten url internally in Django

Note: This approach requires all slugs the be unique globally, so all the segments of the url are unique, which is a bit of a pain, but is doable.